# Deserializing a Binary File to Collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, binary, persistence, deserialization

I'm attempting to deserialize a file and open it up in my program. In this particular program I can save / serialize my collection of customer objects to a file, but when I attempt to de-serialize and reopen the file in the program, it fails. Any Idea why this is failing?

The Following Code is my "Open" button click:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog sfd = new OpenFileDialog();
    Nullable<bool> result = sfd.ShowDialog();
    try
    {
        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        using (Stream fs = new StreamReader("data_to_write.xml"))
        {
            NewAccountList = bf.Deserialize(fs) as ObservableCollection<Contact>;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code of the `Contact` class, that might give more insight into the problem

Comment: And what about sharing the error details?

Answer (score 0):

It has to be said that it is somewhat tricky to answer a question about an error that you have not bothered to describe to us, but having had some experience with serializing and de-serializing data before, I have an idea what it might be. First, I'd say that I see no obvious problem with your code.

When you serialize a data object, it is a refection of that class *at that time*. If you serialize a data object to a file and then make a change to that class, the serialized file will no longer represent that class... it will represent the class before the change(s), but not the current version of it. There would be no way to de-serialize that file using that edited class unless *all* of the changes were undone.

One way to test if you have this problem is to serialize another data object of the same type and then try to de-serialize it straight away. If it de-serializes ok then you have no problem with your code and the problem could well be that your class definition was changed since your object was serialized. If you can't de-serialize it, then you have a problem with your code.